# Returning custom http status codes on AWS Lambda error

Tags: aws-lambda, axios, serverless

I'm working with an AWS Lambda with serverless framework and I want to return a custom http status code when an error occurs but I'm always getting a 502 status code when I call my endpoint with axios.

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

try {
 // some stuff
} catch (err) {
 // error here
 let myErrorObj = {
      errorType : "InternalServerError",
      httpStatus : 500,
      requestId : context.awsRequestId,
      trace : {
        "function": "abc()",
        "line": 123,
        "file": "abc.js"
      },
      body: err
    }

    callback(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
}
}
```

But the object I'm getting back contains the property **status: 502** and **data.message: "Internal server error"**

Any ideas of what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`status code 502` indicates the lambda's response to API Gateway is in an incorrect format.

The correct response for an async function (if not integration method stated in serverless YAML file, it would use `Lambda Proxy Integration`):

```
export const dummyFunction = async (event, context, callback) => 
{
 // ... logic
   return {
   statusCode: 500,
   body: JSON.stringify({...data}),
   }
};
```

Callback is only for non-async function only. Please refer to full [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using API Gateway with your Lambda? If so, what you are returning in the callback is incorrect. The object you return must match this format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

So you can either just `callback(err)` and let AWS generate a 500 or if you want the added error context something like:

```
let myErrorObj = {
    statusCode : 500,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        requestId : context.awsRequestId,
        trace : {
            "function": "abc()",
            "line": 123,
            "file": "abc.js"
        }
        error: err
      }
    })
}
callback(null, myErrorObj);
```

If you want requestId and trace attributes you would need to add them into the body.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting error 502, which could be due to the Lambda function's response being incorrectly formed or containing invalid content. You can use the code below to address this, or for more customized error handling, you can create your own error middleware in your Lambda function.

```
const someHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
    } catch (e) {
       return {
           statusCode: 500,
           headers: {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({
                error: e.message,
                requestId: context?.awsRequestId,
                trace : {
                    "function": "abc()",
                    "line": 123,
                    "file": "abc.js"
                },
                //you can add another context here
           })
       };
   }
 }
 
 export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   // !!!IMPORTANT: Set this flag to false, otherwise the lambda function
   // won't quit until all DB connections are closed, which is not good
   // if you want to freeze and reuse these connections
   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 
   // Run the request
   return await someHandler(event, context, callback);
 }
```